# Role of add() operator in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

What is the role of the add() operator in rxjs? I've read in the docs that in implements a teardown function, but found little info on what a teardown is nor why it is needed exactly. My example below comes from the logic of mat-table (sorting and paginating). Would be great if somebody could explain why the role of the newly created subscription could be and the role of add().

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.loadSomething();
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

let sort$ = this.sort.sortChange.pipe(
  tap(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0))
);

this.subscription.add(
  merge(sort$, this.paginator.page)
    .pipe(tap(() => this.loadSomething()))
    .subscribe()
);
}
```

Comment: this.subscription.add() is used to add chain like array for all your subscribtion, so that you can remove all subscribe method by unsubscribing, so that when component destroy you can unsubscribe to all active subscription.

Comment: Teardown function is a function called when the chain is being disposed. That's after a chain completes, errors or is unsubscribed. Also `add()` is not an operator, it's a method [`Subscription.add()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscription#add) where `Subscription` is an object representing the subscription between observer and Observable that can be disposed.

Comment: Thanks guys, makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Lorenz, add is **not** rxjs operator. It's looks like a code where you store in an array all the subscriptions (in the array `subscription`) to, in ngOnDestroy, unsubscribe to all of them. Sure you has some like

```
ngOnDestroy(){
   this.subscription.forEach(x=>x.unsubscribe())
}
```

Remember that, to avoid memory lack, you should unsubscribe to all your subscriptions.

Other authors prefer to have a subject

```
active: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

Each subscription use takeUntil rxjs operator

```
myObservable.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.active)
).subscribe(res=>....)
```

And use

```
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.active.next();
    this.active.complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is indeed a ngOnDestroy further down in the class that unsubscribes to what has been merged before.

Comment: Be carefull, the `merge` in your code (merge is a rxjs operator) make that you has two observables but an unique subscription. Is this subscription that you add to the array (you should unsubscribe to the subscriptions, not to the observables)